# javascript validatin failing if i enter the value as 1/2

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this JS validation code

```js
function VerifyNumDays(Numdays)
{
  // get the number of errors we've already displayed
  var vErrorMsgCount = document.getElementById('ErrorMsgCount_ID').value;

  if (isNaN(parseFloat(Numdays)) )
    {
      // if we have not displayed this at least once
      if (vErrorMsgCount < 2)
        {  
          alert("Number of days must be a valid number");
        }
        //make sure the button is disabled.
        document.getElementById('SubmitButton_ID').disabled=true;  
        // increment the number of error messages shown so we only show it twice      
        document.getElementById('ErrorMsgCount_ID').value = vErrorMsgCount ++;

        return;
    }
  if( Number(Numdays) <= 0 )
    {
      if (vErrorMsgCount < 2)
        {  
            alert("Number of days must be greater than zero");
        }
      document.getElementById('SubmitButton_ID').disabled=true;
      // increment the number of error messages shown so we only show it twice      
      document.getElementById('ErrorMsgCount_ID').value = vErrorMsgCount ++;
      return;
    }
  
  //have a valid number of days, check to see if it is more than the days between start and end date
  dStart = new Date.parseExact(document.getElementById('calfield1').value , "MM/dd/yyyy");  
  dEnd =  new Date.parseExact(document.getElementById('calfield2').value , "MM/dd/yyyy"); 

  // calculate start date + number of days
  StartCalculated = addDays(dStart,Numdays-1)
  if (StartCalculated > dEnd)         
    {
      alert("Number of days requested is greater than the number of days between start and end dates");
      document.getElementById('SubmitButton_ID').disabled=true;
    }
  else
    {
      // must be a valid number so we can enable the submit
      document.getElementById('SubmitButton_ID').disabled=false;
    }
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
<input type="text"
       name="TotalWorkDays"
       value=""
       style="text-align:center"
       id="TotalDays_id"
       onblur="VerifyNumDays(this.form.TotalWorkDays.value)"  />
</form>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/h7kduteq/

and i am making sure the entry in this field is always number or float value like `1.30` or `2` or any `number` but i am not allowing `1/2` or like `3/4` etc etc, but it seems to be failing there, it is not validating `1/2` as invalid

Comment: `parseFloat("1/2") === 1`, seems like this is related to your issue.

Comment: possiblity it should throw me an alert if this kind of value is passed

Comment: If the [MDN documention](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) is correct, `parseFloat('1/2')` should return `NaN`  ("... or NaN when the first non-whitespace character cannot be converted to a number") (But does it?  Noooo)

Comment: okay, i tried like this ```function circumference(r) {
  return isNaN(parseFloat(r) === 1);
}```  `console.log(circumference('1/2'));` which gives me, so it should throw an error right

Comment: No.  Even if `parseFloat` behaved according to the spec (which it does not), it would not throw an error.  It would return `NaN` which is not the same as an error.  The problem is that `parseFloat` does not return `NaN` when it should.

Comment: Try with `Number()` instead of `parseFloat()`, it gives `NaN` for `'1/2'` and `1.3` for `"1.3"` which seems closer to what you expect.

Comment: @Tibrogargan you can mark as your answer, can you post it please so i can accpt it, number seems to be working good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is caused because you're expecting `parseFloat` to return NaN if it encounters a non-whitespace that can't be included in the number returned.  This is not the [documented behavior](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat):

> parseFloat() picks the longest substring starting from the beginning
> that generates a valid number literal. If it encounters an invalid
> character, it returns the number represented up to that point,
> ignoring the invalid character and all characters following it.

The only time that `parseFloat` will return NaN is literally when the first non-whitespace character in the string cannot be parsed (i.e. there is no number represented up to that point).

Demo:

```js
f = parseFloat
tests = [ ' 1', ' 1a', '1a', 'a', ' a' ]

for (test of tests) {
  console.log(`${f.name}('${test}'):${f(test)}`)
}
```

This differs to the behavior of [Number()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number):

> When used as a function, Number(value) converts a string or other value to the Number type. If the value can't be converted, it returns NaN.

i.e.  The entire value (excluding leading whitespace) must be convertible

Demo:

```js
f = Number
tests = [ ' 1', ' 1a', '1a', 'a', ' a' ]

for (test of tests) {
  console.log(`${f.name}('${test}'):${f(test)}`)
}
```

You can get the behavior you want by changing the first use of `parseFloat` in `VerifyNumDays` to `Number`:

```
if ( isNaN(Number(Numdays)) )
{
    // if we have not displayed this at least once
    if (vErrorMsgCount < 2)
    {  
        alert("Number of days must be a valid number");
    }
    //make sure the button is disabled.
    document.getElementById('SubmitButton_ID').disabled=true;  
    // increment the number of error messages shown so we only show it twice      
    document.getElementById('ErrorMsgCount_ID').value = vErrorMsgCount ++;
    return;
}
```